# PHP outputs a normal question mark instead of ‘ or ’

Tags: php, xml, parsing, encoding

I'm currently parsing an RSS feed and subparsing the html in the description field in order to create a custom XML structure.

In the description field there are ‘ and ’ signs and PHP outputs them as regular question marks. How come?

I've tried different encodings like UTF-8 and iso-8859-1 but nothing works..

This is the xml I'm parsing http://www.ilovetechno.be/artists_rss.xml

This is how it should get parsed http://www.crowdsurferapp.com/clients/ilovetechno/

Comment: Take a look at this question and my answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/php-detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Answer (score 3):

There is a [predefined order in that the encoding of a XML document is to be determined](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding):

1. `charset` parameter in the [HTTP header field *Content-Type*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17):

   ```
   Content-Type: application/xml; charset=<character encoding>
   ```
2. `encoding` attribute in the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-xmldecl):

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="*<character encoding>*"?>

If both are missing, the default character encoding (UTF-8 or UTF-16) is used.

So in order to parse the XML document with the proper encoding, you need to look for those information. Take a look at the question [PHP: Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/php-detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8) for a solution from me.

I also recommend you to use UTF-8 for your internal processing and as the output encoding since that is one of the default character encodings for XML.

Comment: … you missed 3.: Byte order mark. Not sure 2. or 3. has precedence, though.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: You’re right. But I think it’s rather used to choose between the two default encodings if none of the above is present.

Answer (score 0):

you also have to set the correct encoding in your html `meta` tags and/or in your http headers

Comment: Like this you mean? header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

change to utf-8.