# How can I auto-detect ISO 8859-1 versus UTF-8 encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a legacy database table with a mixed encoding. Some lines are [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and some lines are [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Are there some heuristics I can apply on the content of a line to guess which encoding best represents the content?

Comment: So these are the only two encodings in the table ?

Comment: which DB server are you using?

Comment: THis might help you :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: You can have a look at *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/php-detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8* which address the same problem.

Comment: If you are willing to write a script in another language I strongly recommend http://chardet.feedparser.org/, which is pretty reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Convert from UTF-8. If that fails then it's not UTF-8, so you should probably convert from Latin-1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Compare

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text)
```

and

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text)
```

If they are not equal - consider it UTF-8.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? How does it work? Why will the result be different in some cases? What it is doing? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5259448/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).