# General performance optimization

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I am writing a function that returns an array of values to the caller. Let's say the array is:

```
$arr['keyN'] = $valueN;
```

If any '$keyN' does not have a value; its value is entered as zero.

My question is purely from a performance point of view: Is it better to give the key a value of zero or to NOT GIVE IT ANY VALUE AT ALL and have the caller test its presence if(isset($arr[$keyN]))....then execute code?

The reason I am asking this is because giving the array key a zero value will consume main memory and testing its existence will consume CPU cycles. So would it be better to take up some memory space (with a zero value) or not assign anything to the key and have the code test for its existence?

Comment: It is not C language, right?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: It could be any language....but the illustration is in PHP

Comment: Not performance related, but... continuously checking for the presence of a VALID value is redundant and could cause quite a bit of code bloat (and error prone?) depending on your use case. Therefore, I would recommend setting a default value for each element in the array.

Comment: both ram and cpu cycles are a lot cheaper than the time you waist posing the question.

Comment: This smells like premature optimization. The dilemma between space and time optimization is valid, but the answer is specific to your application: do you want it to be faster, or to consume less ressources ?

IMHO you should "optimize" for readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better not to assign nothing, so the value will be NULL, what means that no value is stored to that variable in the "simbolic table". PHP allocates memory in a dinamic fashion, unlike in C, that you would have a memory "block", even if it's useless.

Here I give you a starting link for the reading: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.variables.intro.php

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a SERVER SIDE language; so, 
the client system won't be affected by this, unless you send the answer to the client browser; and in this situation of curse transmitted data should be less ant better to pass up the `NULL` values...
and in server side, there is some lines in php.ini that set the size and execution time of data transfer allowed.
**As a result**, if you want to send the result to client,  pass up the values...
**check this link for other information that will be usefull for you**
[Memory optimization in php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336528/memory-optimization-in-php-array)