# Why database result doesn't show accents?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm migrating a project from a CMS called "Freekore" to CodeIgniter, with my old CMS I didn't have this problem but with CI I can't figure out why I have problems with special characters as `ñ,á,é,í` etc. 
I think I've tried everything. 
I got this in header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

also added this

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```

on database config

```
$db['local']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['local']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

and on config file

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

But I still get this

```
COMUNICACIÃ“N Y PRODUCCIÃ“N EDITORIAL
```

instead of this

```
COMUNICACIÓN Y PRODUCCIÓN EDITORIAL
```

ah and also added this to .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**Edit**
Using [this](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.character-set-name.php) I found out that Current character set is `latin1` but how? I've checked database and tables and are `utf8_general_ci`

**Edit 2**
I did a new database and checked every column collation, now I'm using `utf8_unicode_ci` on the database, on every table and on ever row, but I still have the same problem **Current character set is `latin1`**

**Edit 3**
I decided to use `utf8_decode` and seemed to work but I still have problems with uppercases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours searching for something that help me resolve the problem I found an answer so easy  [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663255/php-mysql-insert-into-utf-8) so before execute the insertion I used this `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` and now the characters are shown as they should. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to encode your data in UTF-8 before you put them into your new db using this function:    http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_encode.asp

Comment: How can I apply this? Do I have to re-insert all the data into the new database?

Comment: Well if you keep the same database structure you just do it table by table grabbing all the data from the table and inserting that into your new database.

    Select * FROM your_original_table

Then in PHP you just grab all the data and when you re-insert you do :
   $query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (".utf8_encode($value1).", ".utf8_encode($value2).", ".utf8_encode($value3).",...)

Comment: I tested with one record, `TÉCNICO` is saved and shown as `TÃƒÂ‰CNICO` :'(

Comment: I had this issue on one of the things i was doing at work, i'm really really busy at the moment but i'll have a look at it and i'll post back if i can find something useful.

Comment: Can you echo the variable which is containing TÉCNICO before you insert into the DB, so we can know if it's a problem related to the DB settings or if it's related to something before plz?

Comment: `string 'TÉCNICO' (length=8)` on database is `TÃ‰CNICO` I changed the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` but the problem remains, but only on CodeIgniter

Comment: Maybe you have to setup code igniter to use UTF8 if it's not already done? This might help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156900/codeigniter-and-charsets

Comment: If you know what kind of characters are a problem you can try to use the str_replace function to replace the bad characters by the good ones, i had to do something like that in my table import files...look :

  $data = str_replace("'", "&#039;", $data);
  $data = str_replace("\\", "", $data);
  $data = str_replace("<br>", "", $data);
  $data = str_replace("<br/>", "", $data);
  $data = str_replace("<br />", "", $data);
  $data = str_replace("  ", " ", $data);

Comment: I've found an easier way, I used `utf8_decode` and it's working, but I still can't understand what is causing this issues. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well, you found the solution yourself that's already a step forward :)
You're very welcome

Comment: Almost found it, I still have issues when the vocal is uppercase :-o

Comment: If you want to put everything on lower case you can use this php function: 

    strtolower ( $your_string_data )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59232/discussion-between-laviku-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

The collation of the database table itself is not UTF-8 unicode. Look here for example in phpmyadmin:

[image]

You need to update the collation. If you do not have phpmyadmin, you can use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `test_table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Did this and nothing changed

Comment: reimport the data. use php utf8_encode() and insert the data again.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change the database collection to UTF 8
execute the following queries .

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

hope it will solve your issue .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely with `utf8_general_ci` (MySQL 5.x default) as your collation. Most people are surprised that not all UTF8 is the same. For the most part you have 3 general "flavors"

- utf8_general_ci
- utf8_unicode_ci
- [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

The difference is in how many bytes are being used for UTF8. `utf8mb4` is the complete UTF8 character set, while `utf8_general_ci` is a small subset that covers most latin character sets, but probably doesn't cover the characters you mentioned. If you switch to `utf8_unicode_ci` it might cover them. The catch is that the more bytes you use, the slower your database will run in processing that data.

This thread discusses it in more detail.
[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: It could be the old data was output in something other than UTF8. What was the old collation?

Comment: The table collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Echo utf8_encode($row['$your_field']);