# Gujarati font showing with square and question marks, how to remove these special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unicode, utf-8

When I'm fetching rows from database, it's showing like below image

[image]

Comment: The might some issue with unicode/non-unicode characters.

Comment: @surajkumar, I think that is problem of UTF-8 Charset Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156900/codeigniter-and-charsets which describe how to configure utf-8 charset in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You are showing raw, set meta UTF-8 in your webpage for showing it

```
<head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

---

```
@font-face {
    font-family: gujarati;
    src: url(gujarati_location.woff);
}
```

Comment: and checked with this function mb_detect_encoding(str), it's showing UTF-8

Comment: no, i have not imported any gujarati fonts. is it required?

Comment: Just should you Try it

Comment: I have not only print it, i have to pass this as variable to fetch rows from other table

Comment: Not displaying and passing a variable are to separate things. Try import font from css to display it. Detail what you have to pass as variable.

Comment: I have to pass $book variable to fetch rows from database, book variable shown in above picture. when i pass this variable it doesn't match so i can't get the required data.

Comment: That has nothing to do with not being showed if you are storing it correctly

Comment: thanks guys..., i got the solution there is nothing big problem actually i was  using ucwords() this function converting my string to some garbage values