# How can import an UTF8 and ISO-8859-1 csv file?

Tags: php, encoding, csv

I have an upload input on a site.
Users can upload csv files with UTF8 or ISO-8859-1 or other encodings.

How can I correctly detect the encoding, convert it to UTF-8 so I can store it inside an UTF-8 DB ?

Comment: question already answered. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/php-detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: If it's just a plain text file, you'll have a *very hard time* guessing encodings.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php) and [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).

There is no 100% safe way to determine the correct chatset, as long as there are no more information then the file itself. If you can be sure it's only these two character sets it should be safe through.