# Unable to encode characters in PHP (Incorrect string value)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to encode Danish characters before sending them to database.

I try to apply this function to them:

```
private function process_array_elements(&$element){
   $element = utf8_encode($element);
   $element = strip_tags(  $element );
   $element = strtolower ( trim ( $element )  );
   $element = mysql_real_escape_string($element);
   return $element;
}
```

Like this:

```
$this->check_line_two = $this->process_array_elements($e);
```

Now, whenever I try to send the string to the database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query="INSERT INTO  result_scanned
          SET line_one= '$this->check_line_one',
              line_two='$this->check_line_two',
              line_three='$this->check_line_three',
              advert_id='$this->advert_id',
              scanned='$this->scan_result'";
```

I get this:

```
 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x83\xE2\xB8r ...' for column 'line_three' at row 1
```

The datatype of the fields in the table are UTF-8 (`utf8_unicode_ci`), so I must encode my string using the same

This thread is related to my question: [Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8).

However, I need to know how to encode any character to UTF-8, before inserting it to the database, otherwise, I get an error as the one aforementioned. I think I need to identify first what kind of characters I am receiving before putting them into database.

Comment: You do `$this->check_line_two`, but the SQL chokes on `for column 'line_three'`

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_` methods. They're old and it's easy to screw something up. Instead, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Also, your function `process_array_elements` (which is a misguiding name for a method, since it has nothing to do with an array, and it can process any kind of string - not something only coming from an array), is taking `$elements` as a reference, but still returning the result. This is confusing and might cause unexpected side effects.

Comment: thanks, kristin,, althought it doesnt relate to the question

Comment: I'm aware, that's why I added it as a comment, not an answer. Still something you should look into, in my opinion. ;-)

Comment: Do not use strtolower, use mb_strtolower (see my answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`utf8_unicode_ci` is the collation, you need the character set as `utf8` as well:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For good measure, make sure that everything is UTF-8 when connecting to MySQL with PHP:

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("DATABASE_NAME") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_database=utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_server=utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

This is how I connect on the [Hebrew gibberish translation](http://gibberish.co.il/) website I run, and it handles everything that myself or that users throw at it.

Comment: it helps.. but there is also a probelm , that i work with different characters..I think i need to encode some of them before putting them into the database... otherwise i get an error

Comment: Just make sure that the HTML page is also UTF-8, that the MySQL table has the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` set properly, and connect to the database as I've shown. Don't try to encode the characters in PHP to save in the database (but please do sanitise them!). Only reencode the characters if you plan on encoding them for an email or to write to a file. Even in those cases, you should consider leaving it as UTF-8 though.

Comment: I get those errors thrown, if i dont encode the characters before puttin gthem into the database

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;` to pastebin and link here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x83\xE2\xB8r ...' for column
```

I only get this error when i use `strtolower`

My database and collation are all UTF-8 and have no problems with characters across the board. I have a language database table that handles Japanese, Russian, Chinese etc. without any issues. This error only popped up when i tried `strtolower`

You need to use PHP's [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) when working with uni-code characters

Comment: This is the only change I needed in my code to fix this error for me.