# encoding a string in php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am executing the following statement.

```
$mystring = <<<EOT
UPDATE sites_niche SET `short_review` = REPLACE(`short_review`, 'â€™',"'");
EOT;
```

However, it doesnt work, as it would work if I placed it in my phpmyadmin. The culprit is this bad character `â€™` that character is simply not being replaced.

I tried to print the update statement to the screen and I get this:

```
UPDATE sites_niche SET `short_review` = REPLACE(`short_review`, 'Ã¢â‚¬â„¢',"'");
```

I think that the string gets garbled as soon as it goes to the database. My question is 
how do encode those sets of characters `â€™` so that they dont get garbled as soon as they go to the database.

Comment: Please have a read of http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I am able to see in your posting .

If you dont know which is your encoding format you can use php mb_detect() function  to check the character encoding format and use the identified format for the solutions below

1. Update to mysql from php

Solution : - Your php code which is responsible for connecting to Mysql should use

```
mysql_set_charset ( string $charset [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

2 .when you print characters are garbled

Solution : - You have to set the character encoding in the page doctype declaration otherwise you will see this garbled characters

Comment: i cant guess the encoding it doesnt work..see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: hmm I had a faced a similar problem , while saving google translated content in to db , fixing the mysql charset solved this issue . As you said I got to know that google serves in UTF-8 , Looks like I have to hack phpmyadmin and get back to you and explain how your query works in phpmyadmin , WRB soon

Comment: What is the column Collation that you are using in the mysql in the table on which you are running this query

Answer (score -1):

You can use the iconv extension http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php or mbstring http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php to convert a string from one charset to other charset

Comment: the problem is that i cant do that, cause i dont know what the original character is encoded to.. so it is like guessing