# MySQL UTF-8 Character insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I am fetching some string from facebook , but i dont know whitch encoding in string . I need to convert this string into utf8 before inserting into database table . Getting this error message. [image: error screenshot]

Here is my php code.

```
$email = (isset($this->_userinfo['email']) ? $this->_userinfo['email'] : '');
$fname = $this->_userinfo['first_name'];
$lname = $this->_userinfo['last_name'];
$name  = $this->_userinfo['name'];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users '
     . '(fbid, fbuid, fullname, userlevel, email, name, sirname) '
     . 'VALUES("'
     . $this->_fbid . '","'
     . $fbuid . '","'
     . $name . '","' 
     . $userlevel . '","' 
     . $email . '","' 
     . $fname . '","' 
     . $lname . '")';
```

Comment: The Facebook API should return all data in one standardized encoding. UTF-8 if I'm not completely mistaken. Read http://kunststube.net/frontback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this question:

[Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

especially the second answer by [Sebastian Grinoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290221/sebastian-grignoli)

He wrote a class (and offers the link to it) which would correctly encode Windows Extended ASCII to UTF8 and also correct UTF8 if necessary.

A really handy tool to have when you are in the UTF8 land :)

Answer (score 4):

did you try this code ?

```
   mysql_query('set names utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to do this for you. Keep in mind this will only work if your data is actually UTF-8 encoded. Unfortunately there is no way to just look at the string and see what encoding it's using.

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

> For me works following code:

$mysqli = mysqli_connect( ... );
mysqli_query( $mysqli, 'SET NAMES "utf8" COLLATE "utf8_general_ci"' );

or just:

mysqli_set_charset( $mysqli, 'utf8' );

Regards, good luck!