# unicode characters in image URL - 404

Tags: php, html, unicode, url-encoding

I am trying to open an image that has Latin characters in its name (`113_Atlético Madrid`).

I saved it by encoding its name with the PHP function `rawurlencode()`, so now its new name is `113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid`. But when I am trying to open it by this URL for example **mysite.com/images/113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid.png** I got 404 error.

How I can fix this issue?

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['Team'])){
    $avatar = $_FILES['Team'];
    $model->avatar = "{$id}_".rawurlencode($model->name).".png";
    if(!is_file(getcwd()."/images/avatars/competitions/{$model->avatar}")){
        move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name']['avatar'], getcwd()."/images/avatars/teams/{$model->avatar}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `rawurldecode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Comment: @Hackerman could you please give an explanation why I need to decode the url ?

Comment: In that piece of code....you are creating a encoded filename...then you ask for the file exist, and if not  you create the file in that folder, right?....now are you sure your check that the file is uploaded?...I think that if you do not use `rawurlencode` your code should work. Think about it, your are saving the image with this name: `113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid.png` right?, then when you try opening that from a browser, even if the file exist, your browser interpret this: `113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid.png` as `113_Atlético Madrid.png`, that is why it returns a 404 error.

Comment: @Hackerman when I decoded it, its new name became `113_Atlأ©tico Madrid` instead of `113_Atlético Madrid`, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%-encoding is for URLs. Filenames are not URLs. You use the form:

```
http://example.org/images/113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid.png
```

in the URL, and the web server will decode that to a filename something like:

```
/var/www/example-site/data/images/113_Atlético Madrid.png
```

You should use `rawurlencode()` when you're preparing the filename to go in a URL, but you shouldn't use it to prepare the filename for disc storage.

There is an additional problem here in that storing non-ASCII filenames on disc is something that is unreliable across platforms. Especially if you run on a Windows server, the PHP file APIs like `move_uploaded_file()` can very likely use an encoding that you didn't want, and you might end up with a filename like `113_AtlÃ©tico Madrid.png`.

There isn't necessarily an easy fix to this, but you could use any form of encoding, even %-encoding. So if you stuck with your current `rawurlencode()` for making filenames:

```
/var/www/example-site/data/images/113_Atl%C3%A9tico%20Madrid.png
```

that would be OK but you would then have to use double-`rawurlencode` to generate the matching URL:

```
http://example.org/images/113_Atl%25C3%25A9tico%2520Madrid.png
```

But in any case, it's very risky to include potentially-user-supplied arbitrary strings as part of a filename. You may be open to directory traversal attacks, where the name contains a string like `/../../` to access the filesystem outside of the target directory. (And these attacks commonly escalate for execute-arbitrary-code attacks for PHP apps which are typically deployed with weak permissioning.) You would be much better off using an entirely synthetic name, as suggested (+1) by @MatthewBrown.

(Note this still isn't the end of security problems with allowing user file uploads, which it turns out is a very difficult feature to get right. There are still issues with content-sniffing and plugins that can allow image files to be re-interpreted as other types of file, resulting in cross-site scripting issues. To prevent all possibility of this it is best to only serve user-supplied files from a separate hostname, so that XSS against that host doesn't get you XSS against the main site.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to preserve the name of the file (and often there are good reasons not to) then it might be best to simply rename the entirely. The current timestamp is a reasonable choice.

```
if(isset($_FILES['Team'])){
    $avatar = $_FILES['Team'];
    $date = new DateTime();
    $model->avatar = "{$id}_".$date->format('Y-m-d-H-i-sP').".png";
    if(!is_file(getcwd()."/images/avatars/competitions/{$model->avatar}")){
        move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name']['avatar'], getcwd()."/images/avatars/teams/{$model->avatar}");
    }
}
```

After all, what the file *was* called before it was uploaded shouldn't be that important and much more importantly if two users have a picture called "me.png" there is much less chance of a conflict.

If you are married to the idea of encoding the file name then I can only point you to other answers:

- [How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings)
- [PHP - FTP filename encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759507/php-ftp-filename-encoding-issue)
- [PHP - Upload utf-8 filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename)

Comment: this is good alternative solution, but it will lead me to change the names for thousands of images.

Comment: Ouch. I always try and store the image filename in the DB so what it is called is irrelevant. I can change naming methods daily and it does not matter.