# can't get UTF-8 names into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding

I'm having a problem getting UTF-8 names written into a MySQL database... Here's what I have.

PHP page head has....

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

the MySQL column is: Char (80) with `utf8_unicode_ci` (these were originally latin1... I've changed them to UTF-8, truncated the database, then rerun the code)

The variable echoes to screen: `Germán Mera`

but writes it to database as `GermÃ¡n Mera`

I tried putting `utf8_encode();` around the variable, but then it writes to database as: `GermÃƒÂ¡n Mera` and screen as `GermÃ¡n Mera` (I know that command only works on iso-8859-1.. I think the JSON page is already UTF-8)

Here is an excerpt of the code I am using to get the name (for sake of simplicity, I'm only showing relevant code - I know what's shown below is not secure)

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/647/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);
$name = $jsonarray['web_name'];
mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO mlsprices (name) VALUES ('$name')");
```

Any idea how I can get this to write to the database properly? When I search, I only get quite complicated answers (eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479832/1217563)) and there's surely an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` after connecting to MySQL:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pw", "db");   
if (!$con)
{
    die('Failed to connect to mySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_errno());
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Comment: Yes I will. It won't let me for 1 more minute. :)