# UTF-8 escaping with HTMLentities returns blank

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, html-entities

I am importing a **CSV fil**e into my database using **MySQL'S LOAD DATA INFILE** command. 
The file is not necessarily **UTF-8 encoded**, I don't have any control over that so i must resort to pre/post processing. ***Both my database and HTML web pages enforce UTF-8 encoding***. Since I do Load Data infile, I have to post process this. So I extract the information out of the database and apply my post processing filters using htmlentities.

```
   foreach($records as $r)
       $updates[] = htmlentities($r["column"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Then I update the DB table again.

The columns go into the table just as they should before the post processing but after that, the columns go blank which means htmlentities returned a blank and that is a valid return value for HTML.

Specifically a candidate value is:

**"PJ Weatherproof 32 ®"**

Any idea why  ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you using `htmlentities()` in the first place? There should be no need for it.

Comment: because should I not need to escape some of these htmlentities ?

Comment: Nope. If everything is properly UTF-8 encoded, there shouldn't be a need for HTML entities.

Comment: it isn't necessarily properly encoded in the CSV file, which is the reason why I must post process...no control over the file

Comment: But if data isn't properly encoded in the CSV file, I don't see how `htmlentities()` can do anything to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "UTF-8" parameter in your call promises `htmlentities()`that the incoming data will be UTF-8. When the data isn't, which will cause the function to return a blank value.

You'll need to try and sniff the encoding, which is an unreliable process and will work well only when you have a very limited set of possible encodings. See e.g. [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911051/187606)

Either way, you can get rid of the `htmlentities()` call - it will do nothing to help the situation, just uselessly add HTML entities where they aren't needed.