# Odd encoding issue after UTF-8 straightens "most" things out

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, thunderbird

Ok, So we have a script that takes emails sent to thunderbird, convertes part of the message to html and saves it to a MySQL. Every file, every part written is set to UTF-8. Finally, on my end of the work, the CRM (written in PHP5.3 expected output Chrome and Firefox), I pull the message, along with other info and display something resembling GMail, but as a "task list" for our employees.

The problem I'm having, if you havn't guessed already, some customer emails are obviously using different encodings. Thus, some (not all, and certainly not majority) of the e-mails don't show all characters correctly.

At first I made use of `utf8_encode` to get the email messages to look right, and this helps with most email messages coming from the database, however, a few slip by with bad characters.

In the DB these "bad apostrophes" appear as `â€™`, but after `utf8_encode` they come through as `�??`. I've tried various encoding things to guess and change as needed, however, this tends to hurt the vast majority of the other emails.

Any suggestions, on one end of the pipe or the other, how I might get these few emails to match everything else, or how i might at least create a possible `preg_replace` filter at the end or something?

### update

it seems even the emails with bad characters are passed to end php as `utf-8` according to `mb_detect_encoding`. This is before any extra encoding. `iconv` does detect the ones that ahve problems, but this really gives me no way to solve them and just puts a php error box up on the screen instead of a simple `FALSE` return that it says it's supposed to give, so this too seems to be no solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't know the encoding of the mail. `utf8_encode` encodes only from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. So you could try to get the encoding with [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and then convert to UTF-8 with [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

EDIT: You could also try to read the `Content-Type`'s charset of the mail.

Comment: I've kind of already been looking at these as a solution, but I've yet to come up with anything that has made any head way. Still the best bet has just been `utf8_encode($msgHTML)`. Any suggestion on a pattern of formula to look for?

Answer (score 0):

### Found My Answer!

Let me start by saying thanks [Sebastián Grignoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290221/sebastian-grignoli) for creating this [VERY handy class](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)([raw](https://raw.github.com/neitanod/forceutf8/master/src/ForceUTF8/Encoding.php)). I ended up working it into my final solution.

Second, I added the class to [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter). For any of you using CI, this is an easy implementation. Simply create a file in `application/libraries` named `Encoding.php` (yes with the capital `e`). Then copy in the [code](https://raw.github.com/neitanod/forceutf8/master/src/ForceUTF8/Encoding.php) to that file, but comment out(or remove) `namespace ForceUTF8` on line 40.

My end result looks something like:

```
echo(Encoding::fixUTF8(utf8_decode($msgHTML)));
```

I'm still double checking, but thus far, I've yet to find one single error!

If I do find another encoding issue after this, I'll make sure to update.

[`SO Question I found that helped.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Comment: Actually, you didn't! By using utf8_decode, you are destroying any characters that are not part of ISO-8859-1. Trying to "fix" these afterwards will not work. And that "fixUTF8" method only works with ISO-8859-1, Win-1252 and UTF-8 - there are many more encodings that can be used, but cannot be fixed. The best solution still is to look at the encoding header in the email and trust it to be true. That's the responsibility of the sender, and there is little reason to believe it is wrong.

Comment: Yes, for a limited subset of test data it will work. Let's talk again later when you stumbled upon a still uncovered encoding. :)

Comment: @Sven besides, I already know that all msg text coming in is being sent by a db that's going to send them as `utf-8`, tho some show up as `ascii` which is just a subpart of `utf-8` of course. breaking them down and using this classes fix command, does exactly what i want. I've yet to find a single broken character since.

Comment: @sven `limited?` I've been looking over 10K+ emails since i employed this solution, no problems yet! Oh and did i mention the company of employees looking at all these emails as well? Since they use this `CRM` to manage their work

Comment: as i said, i will update when there is a problem, but so far, me looking over random thousands of emails, and 40+ employees looking over their own sets have yet to find one.