# How to ensure all my content is UTF-8 and fix encoding issues?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm getting some content from different websites, some of of them send this content type header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

and others

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

I used a Python script using the requests library to check the encoding in bulk:

```
for site in sites:
    r = requests.get(site)

    print r.encoding
```

It printed `UTF-8` for some websites and for the others `ISO-8859-1`, I'm storing these results in a mysql database the collation is `latin1_swedish_ci` which is the default (I'm using XAMPP).

The issue is that these articles have special characters like `é ë ü ï` for some websites these characters become like this `Ã«` which should be `ë`, and the others work fine.

What I'm looking for is a solution to get the same result in both cases, I searched and found some solutions that don't work in both cases, if the string is ok it'll become messed :

```
$str = "Ã«";

echo utf8_decode($str);
```

First I'm sorry about this question, but I had to post it beccause I don't know anything about encoding, so what can I do to get the same result ?

If it matters I'm using [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) to parse the html of these sites, and I'm passing as the options `array('convert_to_encoding' => 'utf-8');`

Comment: Um, seems pretty simple: Make sure it's UTF-8 between fetching it from the web and inserting it into the database. Apparently you know the encoding when you fetch the site (insofar one can know the encoding of a byte stream in the real world).

Comment: @delnan so if my the string contains `Ã«` what should I do before inserting it in the database, currently it's showing as it is, not as `ë`, and thanks.

Comment: Make sure your php.ini has default_charset=utf-8, or set it at the start of your script with `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');`

Comment: Read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Peter In the Python script, first decode from whatever encoding it's in, then encode in UTF-8.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Set your database collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` (phpMyAdmin > select the DB > Operations > Collation). This character encoding can handle a wider range of "exotic" characters than latin1.

You will probably need to re-insert the content with dodgy characters again.

I've never had dodgy character display problems since using this collation for my databases, combined with using the correct UTF-8 charset meta tag in my HTML documents:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

These two actions combined should handle the problem.