# PHP string charset is not stable

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I get data with this code

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
     $content = file_get_contents('http://tr.betboo672.com/services/InPlayApp.mvc/GetInPlaySports?isShrinked=false', false, 
    $context);
    echo $content;
```

Sometimes be problem charset encoding. It is not stable (change character encoding each refresh page). Sometimes get this data

```
���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?
```

mb_detect_encoding function always return UTF-8
I tried this
[Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

Is your page encoding set to utf8?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Yes. I tried. I tried all coding on notepad++. This for balk to access