# How to override default escape function of blade in laravel 5?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I almost solved my problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399160/laravel-5-charset-not-working-correctly-on-the-views-but-it-working-well-when-i). Now I must find a way to override the default blade escape function.
I think there's a way to create a class that extends and override the behavior of BladeCompiler class, this way I could make something like this:

```
class MyCustomCompiler extends BladeCompiler{
   function compileEscapedEchos($value){
        return parent::compileEscapedEchos(utf8_encode($value));
    }
}
```

If I could do it, I only must make laravel use MyCustomCompiler instead BladeCompiler. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to override the compiler, just do this in a Service Provider:

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
```

This will change how `{{ ... }}` is compiled. The default format is `e(%s)`.