# Plain Mail in Laravel and UTF-8 characters

Tags: laravel

When I send a Multipart mail, HTML view renders correctly but when I activate plain text view it doesn't render accents. How could I send accents in plain text mail using Laravel?

Method used to send mail

```
Mail::send(['html.blade.php', 'text.txt'], $data, $callback);
```

Sending `áéíóú` through a form results in:

**HTML**

```
áéíóú
```

**Plain Text**

```
&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute;
```

Here's the text view content:

**text.blade.php**

```
Information Request
====================================================

{{ $user_message }}

--
{{ $name }}
{{ $email }}

** This mail was sent from mysite.com **
```

And I'm retrieving information from the controller in this way:

**WelcomeController.php**

```
public function contact(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
  $data = array(
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
    'user_message' => $request->get('message')
  );

  Log::info('DEBUGGING $data['user_message']);

  \Mail::send(['emails.html', 'emails.text'], $data,
    function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
    $message->to('info@mysite.com', 'Webmaster / My Site')
      ->subject('Info Request');
  });
}
```

When I enter áéíóú on the form. `Log::info` returns áéíóú

Comment: I've tried what you described and it works fine for me. But then again I just placed the `áéíóú` in a view file and sent that. Where are those HTML entities coming from? Are they part of some data fetched from the database? Please post the text view file.

Comment: Can you provide code from html.blade.php?
Did your html.blade.php has utf-8 meta tag: 
<meta charset="utf-8">

If you use htmlentities to output data, make sure it looks like this: htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

Also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442687/how-to-override-default-escape-function-of-blade-in-laravel-5/30443736#30443736 ... could be helpfull

Comment: @Bogdan data is captured using a form. I edited the question with the text view file.

Comment: Btw, placing áéíóú directly on the view do work. But when they come from the contact form they're displayed as html entity. @gandra404 tried `Blade::setEchoFormat` but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try `{!! $var !!}` instead of `{{ $var }}`.

`{{ }}` in a blade template runs `htmlentities()` before displaying.

See here for more information:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data