# Emoticons in query Laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Mysql store some emoticons: .

I have 2 `Laravel` version `5.2.10` & `5.1.23 (LTS)`, get data from `Mysql` with code:

```
return DB::table('table')->get();
```

In version `5.1.23 (LTS)`, it working fine, but with `5.2.10`, it show `"????"`.

By the way, the same error when insert emoticons between 2 version.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you have character encoding issues, the 2 code uses different characters sets to access and display the data.

Comment: I do not know laravel, so I cannot help you with the specifics.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442687/how-to-override-default-escape-function-of-blade-in-laravel-5/30443736#30443736