# Laravel 5.1 Blade view output charset not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I have encountered a strange situation. After releasing the project to the release server some characters are not displaying correctly, however running the project on c9.io server works just fine.

For example:

This is what I'm seeing in c9.io [image: c9.io]

And this is what I see in the release.  [image: release]

HTML's, databases and database configs have charset set to UTF-8

Snippet of the code used to list the elements in the blade template

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach($menu as $item)
          <li><a href="/{{$item[App::getLocale()]['url']}}">{{$item[App::getLocale()]['name']}}</a></li>
     @endforeach
</ul>
```

As I can see, the š character displays correctly, any ideas why would this happen? Maybe there is a config I missed?
This occurs in any {{ $variable }} output throughout the project.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442687/how-to-override-default-escape-function-of-blade-in-laravel-5/30443736#30443736) did not fix my problem

Comment: try {!! ... !!}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did not see that when migrating to the production database one function, which retrieves localized string in MySQL lost its correct charset. Changing back to UTF-8 did the trick and solved the problem.