# Unicode characters (emojis) from MySQL displayed as "????"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unicode, laravel-5

On a MySQL table, the column `release_notes` is encoded in utf8mb4.

On the Laravel `config/database.php` file, the following is under the MySQL section:

```
'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

From a MySQL client, I set the value of that column to an emoji (e.g. ""). It is properly displayed on the MySQL client.

To display that column, on the Blade template I have the following:

```
{!! nl2br($app->release_notes) !!}
```

However, what ends up displaying on the browser is:

> ????

To verify this is not a browser/HTML problem, I hardcoded the emoji directly on the template file and it is displayed as expected.

I did try [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30485448/112335), to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: could it be something as simple as adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the `<head>` section of your template...? seems like the hard coding test you ran would rule that out, though

Comment: Right, and I already have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

Comment: how about the font? could the page be trying to display the character in a font that doesn't have the symbol? again, not likely, but want to knock out the obvious, easy stuff first

Comment: Nope, changed from Source Sans Pro to Arial, but it still doesn't work. Also, this would have been ruled out by the hardcoded emoji as well.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 4 question marks?  The Emoji is 4 bytes long.  The likely cause is trying to transform non-latin1 characters into a `CHARACTER SET latin1` column.

Check all these:

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.