# How to find out what encode it is?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow detect what encode type text is using for example if there is word "Šanęrt", it's UTF-8 and if it's "Projekto UÅ¾duoÄ•iÅ³ Ataskaita" would write what encode it is. Because my site creates PDF file, and I can't find why it writes Å¾ - these symbols and not letters.

And I think, if I could find out what encode it is I could decode to UTF-8 to write normally. For example if it is UÅ¾duoÄ•iÅ³, normal it would be - Užduočių. Here is the simple code:

```
$pdf->ezText("\n" . $AppUI->_('Project Completed Task Report'), 12);
```

When locale set to Lithuanian it writes `Pabaigto Projekto UÅ¾duoÄ•iÅ³ Ataskaita`.

Comment: _i was wondering if it is possible to somehow detect what encode type text is using_ Technically yes, there is a method for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php . Did you try it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below procedure :

```
<?php
$ary[] = "ASCII";
$ary[] = "JIS";
$ary[] = "EUC-JP";
$ary[] = "UTF-8";
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, $ary);

?>
```

The thing in `$ary[]` is that we need to provide the names of encoding to check against it.

**Edited:**

```
<?php

    $ary[] = "ASCII";
    $ary[] = "JIS";
    $ary[] = "EUC-JP";
    $ary[] = "UTF-8";
    foreach( $ary as $ar )
    {
      $check = mb_detect_encoding($str, $ar);
        if($check)
        {
          die("Your Encoding is:".$ar);
        }
    }

?>
```

Whenever you're encoding will be encountered it will die there to show your encoding type.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Can you help me, because when i use this it writes that it is UTF-8. But why it is symbols then? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  function `iconv_get_encoding($str)` to get encoding from string

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv-get-encoding.php

You may be interested also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8) and [this](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)