# Utf-8 strings won't convert similary. I want all the scraped text become the same for saving in database

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, file-get-contents, encode

I have huge problems with encodings. I'm scraping text from some other sites with `file_get_contents()`. And the quotes becomes special odd characters or questionmarks. But the strange thing is that some text from different sites ARE utf-8, but the quotes becomes different things when I receive it. When I run `utf8_decode()` a quote from one utf-8 text becomes a quote. Bot in another utf-8 text from another site it becomes a questionmark.

Is there any way to fix so all text is looking good when I save it to db.

The charset in database table is `latin1_swedish_ci`, and I have tried to change it to `utf8_unicode_ci` but did no difference.

**Edit:**

Have now tried a little bit more. These two works for different texts. This one works for one text:

`$source = utf8_encode($source);`

And this are working for the others:

`$source = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');`

But you can't put the string through both. They are not working together. They destroy the other ones for each other.

Printscreen without any encoding (text is in Swedish):

[image]

**Edit:**

FYI: I have now changed the table to `utf8_unicode_ci`. However, still not working. Here are all the functions I've tried with:

[image]

Actually, if I just leave it like this, most of the texts are outputted with right characters. It's just some where `"` becomes `Â”`.

Comment: take a look sounds similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8 maybe this helps to get the sources clean before you decode it

Comment: Gets syntax error on `use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;`

Comment: The person voted this down. Please motivate.

Answer (score 0):

can you please dump the code you grabbed using print_r?

notice: your html page must have a correct meta-charset to display unicode characters correctly.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Does the page need right meta-charset even for text fields like `<input value="">`? I'm printing them there. I add a printscreen in my post above now.. Everything is in Swedish. And content-type is UTF-8 yes.

Comment: well yes, wherever you decide to output your data (even inside the attribute value of an inputbox), the meta charset should always be declared accordingly to the DB collation.

Comment: I just want all the text going into DB to be the same type... Don't know what to do :/