# Converting from XML to json with json_encode messes up the encoding of the string

Tags: php, json, xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a string that receives an XML structure. 
One of the elements contains Chinese characters. 
In order to covert the XML to json, I use json_encode(). The output for the Chinese characters is garbled.

I tried checking the encoding with mb_detect_encoding and even tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8).

I've googled around (a lot) and found numerous other resources but none of them seems to solve my problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootjson>
  <widget>
    <debug>on</debug>
    <text>
      <data>點擊這裡</data>
      <size>36</size>
      <alignment>center</alignment>
    </text>
  </widget>
</rootjson>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
if ($encoding = mb_detect_encoding($xml, 'UTF-8', true)) echo 'XML is utf8';  //It finds it to be utf8
$json = json_encode($xml, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
if ($encoding = mb_detect_encoding($json, 'UTF-8', true)) echo 'Json is utf8';  //It also finds it to be utf8
var_dump($json);
?>
```

Output:

```
{
    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "text": {
            "data": "\u9ede\u64ca\u9019\u88e1",
            "size": "36",
            "alignment": "center"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think I can trust the mb_detect_encoding here as it is telling that both $xml and $json are UTF-8 encoded. The Chinese string 點擊這裡 is now showing as

> \u9ede\u64ca\u9019\u88e1

.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. What you need is JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Comment: You're so right!! Thanks a lot, I looked at the manual and didn't realize that. If you'd like to formally answer the questions I can vote it up and mark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, see the documentation at [php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)