# Arabic word in codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this route `$route['wwww/(:any)'] = 'aaa/nnn/mmm/$1';`
when `any` is an Arabic word this route doesn't work.
How can fix this problem?

Comment: most likely you're not using a `UTF-8` character encoding. Try changing your app and server settings accordingly. Further reading [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)