# How to use Codeigniter routes with Arabic letters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, config

Please help me

I have this route

$route['rental/(:any)'] = 'site/landing/display_product_detail/$1';

When value any variable is English working fine, but when value it Arabic doesn't work.?

please, Anyone can help me in detail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arabic word in codeigniter route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637534/arabic-word-in-codeigniter-route)

Comment: You already asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637534/arabic-word-in-codeigniter-route) . No need to repost